If I have a child class that needs to add information to a parent's existing toString() override, how would I do that in C#?
This is my first question here, so hopefully I'm doing things right.
We have an assignment where we basically have to make a mini weather channel (it's supposed to be teaching us more about inheritance and abstract classes). I think I sort of understand it for the most part, but one part is tripping me up:

It {the child class, using Rain as an example} must overload the toString() method of its parent class to add information to it. The information is the Rain's drop size, as well as their classification {large, medium, or small}.

The original toString() override I wrote (parent class) was formatted like this:
Weather Event Location: {location}
id: {id}
active: {active}
Rate of Fall: {rateOfFall} in/h ({Light/Medium/Heavy})

But the child class needs to add things on to look like this:
Weather Event Location: {location}
id: {id}
active: {active}
Rate of Fall: {rateOfFall} in/h ({Light/Medium/Heavy})
Drop size: {dropSize} ({Small/Medium/Large})

I guess what I'm trying to ask is...is the existing format already inherited by the child? As in, would I only need to add the "Drop size" portion to the child class, or do I just have to write the whole thing out while including the new information in it as well? There wasn't any information concerning how to do this in our notes, so I'm a little lost.

Please add your code to your question! It should be possible for the child class to call the parent class's ToString() method by calling base.ToString() and just add to that, but without the code it isn't possible to say for certain.

There’s no one right way to do this, and especially in artificial tasks like many school assignments, best practice can get a little unclear. But consider that you can call *base.ToString().

super is Java, base is C#. Adding info to one returned by the parent is as simple as public override string ToString() => base.ToString() + Environment.Newline + "Extra info";
